# Lots of debug area errors with swift xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, firebase

I get a lot of errors using my app in the simulator, after I updated xcode to 8.0.

My app is using Firebase and Facebook login. Earlier, I wasn't able to login with the facebook button, but I read about it and found out I needed to enable keychain sharing - now I am able to login with the facebook button on simulator, but I am still getting A LOT of errors. Here are some of them:

[image]

Is it possible to get rid of them? How? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this step:

I have the same issue, but there is something you can do to -> Go in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
Then on Run Section on the left, select Argument Tab and in Environment Variable put this :

OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to value : disable.